# Castle Windsor and WCF Web Api Message Handlers

Tags: castle-windsor, wcf-web-api

I'm trying to use Castle Windsor to create my message handlers because just using ...

```cs
MessageHandlers.Add(typeof(MyHandler));
```

... doesn't allow me to use constructor injection of other services, for example a logger

So, I've create an installer which registers all my handlers (of which there is currently one!)

```cs
public class MessageHandlerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            AllTypes
                .FromThisAssembly()
                .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof (DelegatingHandler)))
                .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Custom(InstallerContext.LifestyleManager))
            );
    }
}
```

This works fine, when I run it through the debugger I can see the extra component registration in the container.

But when I try to set up the message handler factory for WCF Web Api it doesn't appear to work. (I have breakpoints in the SendAsync method which never gets hit)

```cs
public class MyApiConfiguration : WebApiConfiguration
{
    public MyApiConfiguration(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        EnableTestClient = true;
        IncludeExceptionDetail = true;

        CreateInstance = ((serviceType, context, request) => container.Resolve(serviceType));
        ErrorHandlers = (handlers, endpoint, description) => handlers.Add(container.Resolve<GlobalErrorHandler>());
        MessageHandlerFactory = () => container.ResolveAll<DelegatingHandler>();
    }
}
```

So, I'm obviously missing something. I just don't know what it is. Can anyone enlighten me?

**EDIT** (extra config code, as requested)

```cs
public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    AddServiceRoutes(routes);
}

private static void AddServiceRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    Container = WindsorContainerBootStrap.CreateContainerAndInstallComponents<PerThreadLifestyleManager>();
    var config = new EtailApiConfiguration(Container);
    routes.MapServiceRoute<CustomersApi>("customer", config);
    routes.MapServiceRoute<ConsumerApi>("consumer", config);
    routes.MapServiceRoute<PricePlansApi>("priceplans", config);
}
```

**EDIT 2** (The Solution)

I had a constructor to my Handler like so ...

```cs
    public MyHandler(DelegatingHandler innerChannel, ILogger logger)
        : base(innerChannel)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

... that wasn't getting called despite the changing the init code to use a lambda ...

```cs
MessageHandlerFactory = () => container.ResolveAll<DelegatingHandler>();
```

... so I added another constructor which just takes an `ILogger` and all is well. I figured that my container didn't know what a Delegating Handler was and that the `MessageHandlerFactory` must be dealing with that somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the lambda for ctor injection, that is why it is there.  BTW, you are missing a ()

How are you registering your routes, are you passing in the configuration object?

Comment: hmm, i'll try that. if that's the case then its a FAIL for resharper! (it told me it could be simplified down to what I had originally in the question)

Comment: You had no "()" for the method ResolveAll. As for the lambda, the compiler does interpolate it as it is a method group, but I don't think it's as obvious / commonly known.

Comment: @GlennBlock,AntonyScott : could you please post the code of the same